# What is the authenticity of the hadith prohibiting cutting nails and hairs for those who want to sactifice on eid al-adha?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, authenticity, eid-ul-adha, udhiyyah

What is the authenticity and interpretation of the hadith prohibiting cutting nails and hairs for those who want to sacrifice an udhiyyah on eid al-adha?

AFAIK this hadith is compiled in Musnad Ahmad and one of the sunan (maybe ibn Majah or an-Nasa'i?)

The hadith basically say that a person (man?) who is intending to do the sacrifice (udhiyyah) should stop cutting his nails and hair (until this is done).
I'd like to understand the interpretation from these perspectives:

- if the hadith is authentic how does it go along with the recommendation of being clean (tahara) etc.
- when should one start (leaving hair and nails grow), once the intention or decision is made or at the moment one has bought a sheep or any other valid udhiyyah (is it a niyyah or a qasd matter?)
- When should one cut his hair and nails again, right after the udhiyyah is slaughtered or later or sooner (after Eid prayer, day of Eid)?
- how much should one stick on this and are there conditions allowing not to do so, lets say I just wanted to cut my nails, but if i left them 10 more days they would be too long ...

Comment: I guess you are speaking about this hadith: https://sunnah.com/muslim/35/53

Comment: Comments by Nawawi: http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=5952&idto=5958&bk_no=53&ID=937

Comment: @Kilise you could write an answer based on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hadith is from Sahih Muslim (https://sunnah.com/muslim/35/57):

> Umm Salama, the wife of Allah's Apostle (ﷺ), reported Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ) to have said: He who has a sacrificial animal with him
>   whom (he intends) to offer as sacrifice, and he enters the month of
>   Dhu'I-Hijja, he should not get his hair cut or nails trimmed until he
>   has sacrificed the animal.

It is sahih as it is in collected by imam muslim.

Time starts when the crescent of the month is sighted and the month begins. The hadith says this.

Time ends when you have slaughtered the animal. The hadith says this directly. You can cut them at any time after the sacrifice.

There is no clash with hygiene. I cut my nails a day or two before the month starts, they are barely grown in 10 days. If they are grown then clean them with a toothpick or spray water etc.